# How to return number of object occurrence in a list according to certain parameters JAVA

Tags: java, list, loops, iterator

I have a java list of objects, i want to know the number of occurrences where `object.certain_attribute = foo`. I do know about `Collections.Frequency()` but this function requires that i send the exact same object, whereas i only want to get the objects that are similar in accordance to a certain attribute.I have 
simply looped over the whole list and compared but can you guide me with some easier way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i do know that i can simply loop over the whole list and compare, but i'm asking to see if there's an easier way. Trying not to re-invent the wheel here

Comment: *want to get the objects that are similar* what do you mean by `similar`

Comment: I think you will end up counting if a criteria meet....

Comment: hmmm, i maybe have said it wrong, yeah not similar but lets say its a geometric object i want to search where the `object.color = green`

Answer (score 1):

in that case you can use a stream and filter the green 
ones..

example

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1));
long xFreq = x.stream().filter(t -> t % 2 == 0).count();
```

in your case somthing similar depending on what is that color for a type.

```
long xFreq = x.stream().filter(c -> c.getColor().equals("green")).count();
```

Comment: You don't need `.collect(Collectors.toList()).size()` when you only want the size of the list, just call `.count()` instead.